# Calculate the value of x, y and z coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems

System of the equations:

Equation 1:

$$-360 = -6x + x^2 - 40y + y^2 - 20z + z^2$$

Equation 2:

$$-600 = -40x + x^2 - 30y + y^2 - 100z + z^2$$

Equation 3:

$$59.85 = -10x + x^2 - 4y + y^2 - 10z + z^2$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you share what you have tried and what issues you are having so people can provide better guidance? Regards

Comment: $59.85 = \frac {1197}{20}$. Where on Earth did that come from? In fact, where did any of this come from?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying
to find the intersection of three spheres
(with equation $r^2 = (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2$
or $x^2-2ax+y^2-2by+z^2-2cz = r^2-a^2-b^2-c^2$).

Anyway, the equations are

$\begin{align}
a &=-360 = -6x + x^2 - 40y + y^2 - 20z + z^2\\
b&= -600 = -40x + x^2 - 30y + y^2 - 100z + z^2\\
c&= 59.85 = -10x + x^2 - 4y + y^2 - 10z + z^2\\
\end{align}
$

Subtracting the first two,
$a-b = 34x -10y +80z$.
Subtracting the last two,
$b-c = 30x -26y -90z$.

These will let you get
any two of $x, y$, and $z$
in terms of the other.
For example,
you might get
$y = px+q$
and $z = rx+s$
for some $p, q, r, $and $s$.

Substitute these expressions in any of
your equations
and you will get a quadratic for $x$.
For example,
if you substitute these in the first equation,
you get
$\begin{align}
a 
&= -6x + x^2 - 40y + y^2 - 20z + z^2\\
&=-6x + x^2 - 40(px+q) + (px+q)^2 - 20(rx+s) + (rx+s)^2\\
&=-6x + x^2 - 40px-40q + p^2x^2+2pxq+q^2 - 20rx-20s + r^2x^2+2rxs+s^2\\
&=-x(6+40p+20r+2pq+2rs) + x^2(1+p^2+r^2) +q^2 -40q-20s +s^2\\
\end{align}
$

Solve this quadratic in $x$
and you will get
0, 1, or 2 real roots depending how
the three spheres intersect.
Get $y$ and $z$ for each $x$ and you have your solutions.

To see how the spheres can intersect,
look at two spheres.
They can be disjoint,
be tangent,
or intersect in a circle.
Adding a third sphere
allows for no common points,
one common point if the sphere
passes through the tangent point,
or two points if the
sphere passes through the circle of intersection.

There is also the possibility of
two of the spheres coinciding,
in which case
the intersection could also be a circle.
In this case, the three original equations
would not be linearly independent.